# ReactJS with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I try to add ReactJS in my custom module but I don't have any idea to How to integrate ReactJS with Magento 2 frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Add these urls in head section of default.xml file:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
```

add this in your template file:

```
<div id="app"></div>    

<script type="text/babel" src="example.js"></script>
```

Add new file of js example.js and put below code into it:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <p>
        More info <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank">here</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Application />, 
   document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: I have a react.js build so how to integrate it with magento 2

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise just to use knockout.js as this is natively integrated within magento. That having said if you wanted to make React components for any part of the store except the checkout.

- The way to go would be to add react and react-dom to your theme in the web/js folder in your custom theme.
- Then set up the require-config.js so that those files can be used in a phtml
- Create a new template block through the layout system
- require both react and react-dom within a script tag
- now you can use react inside that script tag.

This is the fastest way to get react running on your magento store. You probably also want to set up something with webpack so you can use jsx. And es6 syntax in older browsers. but if browser support is not an issue and you don't need jsx ..then the above should work with almost no setup